# Does twitter bootstrap always take a lot of time to load in firefox?

Tags: xml, firefox, xslt, twitter-bootstrap-2

I am using Firefox 10.0.2 on Mac OSX Lion and using Twitter Bootstrap 2.1.1 . I am transforming an xml file to html using xslt. The file is pretty huge and i thought that was the reason that the page load takes a lot of time. But when i look at the console i see that the remaining stuff take very minor time when compared to the time spent on errors and warnings in bootstrap.min.css . Kindly take a look at the screenshot below.

[image]

These errors take up 6 seconds easily. All the other components in my xml file load pretty fast. Is there any way that i can make the page load sooner and eliminate these errors ?

EDIT: Heres the link to the image, so its viewable. https://i.stack.imgur.com/W41En.png